# Adding border to textbox in asp gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm currently building an ASP.NET GridView in which, values from a specific column have to be editable directly by clicking on them.

I managed to do that this way :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$Resources:i18n, Projets_Tableau_Désengagement %>" ItemStyle-Width="1%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Comments">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="Disengagement" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("Disengagement") %>' 
          BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="OnDisengagementChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /> 
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Everything works fine and it does exactly what I wanted, a textbox without border, that looks like a label and is editable.

But my issue here is that I'd like to have borders when there's a click on it. I tried many solutions implementing javascript or CSS but none of them seem to work (could be because of my lack of skills in Web programming though).

Since there's the "TextChanged" event that is handled server side, I will then remove the border after the user as changed the text in the textbox, everything should work out of the box.

But is there a way to add a border "OnClick" in code-behind?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in any event you want.

The parameters every event is receiving are:

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

the `sender` is the reference of the component raising the event. You simply need to do this:

```
(sender as TextBox).BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None; //or what ever you want
```

Comment: How can I use the sender ? I mean, what would be the method definition in code-behind ?

Comment: @ElCapitaine You just need to create an event method, and copy paste the last line of code of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row command in my opinion as shown below step wise:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="gvOnRowCommand" .../>
```

and on your control

```
<asp:TextBox CommandName="AnyName" ... />
```

In code behind

```
protected void gvOnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AnyName")
        {
            //your code to add border
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "OnRowCommand" is not triggered when Clicking in a TextBox.